# how can i dismiss a viewcontroller whilst at the same time segue onto a different one

Tags: swift, xcode, segue, viewcontroller

I am currently unable to dismiss a viewcontroller and at the same time make the application move to a different controller without experiencing a few bugs. What my code does currently is when the timer 'secondsRemaining' hits zero it will dismiss the current viewcontroller it is on and will show the previous viewController that is displayed underneath the current viewcontroller being the 'homeScreenViewController'. Because of this it will not call the code- `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "gameScreenToHighscore", sender: self)`.

Current code:

```
@objc func updateTimer() {
            if secondsRemaining > 0 {
                secondsRemaining -= 1
                timerLabel.text = "Timer:\(secondsRemaining)"
                print(secondsRemaining)
            } else {
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "gameScreenToHighscore", sender: self)
                
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best approach is that you handle the navigation in the parent ViewController, You can achieve this by making `delegate`.

In the ChildViewController:

```
@protocol ModalVCDelegate {
    func navigateToTheSecondVC()
}

class ModalViewController {
    weak delegate: ModalVCDelegate!
}
```

and you should call the delegate method when the timer has done.

```
delegate?.navigateToTheSecondVC()
```

And Also in the ParentViewController, you should set the delegate:

```
childVC.delegate = self
present(childVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

and then:

```
extension MainViewController: ModalVCDelegate {
    func navigateToTheSecondVC {
       dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "gameScreenToHighscore", sender: self)
       })
    }
}
```

Comment: hi in the line of code beginning with extension, should the "EmployeePickerDelegate" be ModalVCDelegate?